# Why don't I see ASP.NET MVC 4 or MVC 5 in my control panel after installing Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

This should be an easy question for anyone experienced working with ASP.NET MVC. I am just beginning (finally) to learn ASP.NET MVC. I have VS2012 Pro on my laptop. I just purchased and installed VS2013 Pro. When I go into my (Win 7 Pro 64-bit) control panel, I expected to see either ASP.NET MVC 4 and/or ASP.NET MVC 5 listed. But neither are there. Do I have to download and install MVC 4 and MVC 5 AFTER having installed VS2013 Pro? I would have expected at least MVC 4 to have been installed automatically along with VS2013. TIA.

Final note: For those just getting started with VS2013 and wanting to do an MVC 5 project, I found a reference that shows exactly how to get to the MVC 5 template, such as it is:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

It is not that intuitive, there are several custom MVC 5 templates (with varying bits and pieces of plumbing) on NuGet when you look under the "Online" templates, but to just use the default MVC 5 plumbing for a new web application project, the article shows how to drill down to a template that is only named "MVC", not "MVC 5". If they hadn't dropped the number off the template it would have been more obvious, but that's Microsoft  ;-)

And finally, what it says at the top of this page:

This question already has an answer here:
MVC3 missing in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

is NOT correct. That question does NOT provide the answer to this question, because the way MVC is deployed has changed throughout the visual studio versions, as one can see by reviewing all of the text on this page.

Comment: So, I'm assuming the answer to my question is that I do have to download/install ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET MVC 5 after installing VS2013 Pro.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the one marked. Please re-read the question. The OP is wondering why MVC isn't in the control panel (**Programs and Features**), not why MVC isn't in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, like Rowan said it isn't as simple as the supposed duplicate of something talking about VS2010.  I just went into VS2013 and after rummaging around I found the MVC 4 template, but it is underneath "Web, Visual Studio 2012". But I still don't see where the project template for MVC 5 is.  So I'm STILL wondering if I wanted to do an MVC 5 project, where that template is within VS2013... or, does simply creating a website instead of a project, I end up with an MVC 5 app by default?

Comment: You should just create an MVC project. It defaults to MVC5 in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 comes with MVC ready-to-go.

For previous versions of Visual Studio you have to download and install MVC separately. Starting with about [2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2012/aspnet-and-web-tools-20131-for-visual-studio-2012) MVC is now included rather than a separate installation.

Comment: Hmmm... then shouldn't I see a "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4" entry in my control panel programs, or is it the deal that it is actually in VS2013 but the VS2013 install process doesn't write an entry for it to the Control Panel? That's interesting :)

Comment: You won't find it in the control panel **Programs and Features** section. It's bundled *inside* Visual Studio 2013.